# Helidon background task

Tags: java, helidon

I have a **@ApplicationScoped** bean in my Helidon MP microservice, is there a way to force the creation of the bean at server startup instead at first method call?

I need this bean ready and running just after server startup but every attempt I made it's inconclusive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to solve it.
If your bean observes the initialization of `ApplicationScoped` it will be instantiated during startup phase. It's a trick but it works fine.

```
public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object init) {

}
```